# Parallel rxJs Observables without waiting for all to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Is there a way to request many similar requests in parallel using rxJs Observables in parallel **without** waiting for all requests to complete. I want to handle as each one comes. I don't want to use a loop of requests. Use case is one of the request is slow and there are many of them
I tried forkJoin (below) but it waits for all to complete. and mergeMap is not taking an array. Any help? Thanks

```js
/*
  // example of many posts
  const post1 = getPostHTTP(1);
  const post2 = getPostHTTP(2); // A slow post
  const post3 = getPostHTTP(3);
  ...
*/

const promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    promises.push(getPostHTTP(i))
}

forkJoin(promises).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
        //displayPost
    })).subscribe(posts => {
        posts.forEach((post: any) => {
            displayPost(post)
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a mix of `from` and `mergeMap` is what you are looking for. The code could look like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    promises.push(getPostHTTP(i))
}

from(promises).pipe(
  mergeMap(post => displayPost(post)),
).subscribe(
  next: result => {// do something with the result of each displayPost operation},
  error: err => {// handle errors},
  complete: () => {// do something when everything is completed}
)
```

Comment: interesting, there is "from" operator, lemme check this out

Comment: this worked perfect, thank you. I wasn't aware that there is from operator.  You opened my eyes because later on I can even use this for concatMap if a use case requires series request

Comment: Let me suggest you [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a). It may give you some inspiration around typical cases of use of rxjs with http.

Comment: I have another question on this. I tried finalize inside the pipe, but it seemed to be called before everything finishes. Why is that so. I would like to do some final things like loading = false; @Picci the article needed to sign up, so couldn't get to it, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Tremmillicious https://archive.ph/VSVvG

Answer (score 1):

You should convert `Promise` to `Observable` via `from` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) and merge them into one `Observable` via `merge` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge).

It will be like:

```
merge(...promises.map(p => from(p))
    .subscribe(post => {
        // do smth with post
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the mergeMap and the Observable.from from @Picci answer above.

Comment: @Tremmillicious merge will convert promises to observables for you. So you don't need `from` at all. `merge(...promises).subscribe(...` is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise` API to send multiple requests simultaneously and await them all to resolve.

If you have a condition that you need to run those promises sequentially, then this solution might not work for you.

Excerpt is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#sofortige_ablehnung).

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'one');
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'two');
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'three');
});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, 'four');
});
var p5 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject('reject');
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});

//From console:
//"reject"

//You can also use .catch
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
}).catch(reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});
```

Comment: generally not a bad answer but does not match the requirements since op explicitly mentioned that he don't want the code to wait for all requests to complete.

Comment: This is the same as what rxJs forkJoin is doing on my example. I didn't wanna wait for all to complete. Wanna "do stuff" as they arrive one by one