# RxJs MergeMap and finalize not working as expected (as I thought)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am having problems with finalize or complete using the code below. I want to be able to call `loading = false` after all is done. I tried to use finalize and complete but it is being called too early and multiple times. Any help? Thanks

```js
displayPost(postDetail) {
  //some rendering stuff
  renderHTML(postDetail);
}

// returns a post query object 
getPostQuery(username, postId) {
 query: `{
        post (id:"${username}", postId:"${postId}") {
          id
          title
          content }`
  return query;
}

let loading = true
//getUserHTTP() is an http request
getUserHTTP(userId).pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    const ids = [];

    // let's say oldest 100 posts
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      ids.push(getPostQuery(user.username, i))
    }

    return from(ids);
  }),
  mergeMap(query => this.httpClient.post(url, query)),
  finalize(() => {
    //this is being called too early and multiple times
    loading = false;
  })
).subscribe({
  next: result => { /* doing staff */ displayPost(result) },
  error: err => { /* handle errors */ },
  complete: () => { /* not working */ }
})
```

Comment: Please provide the code for `displayPost`.

Comment: I have edited and added more context, but basically it is an HTTP query

Comment: What is `promises`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ids.push(...)`?

Comment: Is there are probability that you are calling `getUserHTTP()` multiple times? I looked trough the rxjs part and it seems legit.

Comment: I have edited to ids.push(...) Typo, thanks

Comment: @ХристиянХристов that's a good point, lemme check real carefully. Also does mergeMap have limit of concurrence? Default is undefined? Still new with deep rxJs

Comment: According to the source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts  , there are no limits.

If you can create a working stackblitz i will try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

`mergeMap` would trigger multiple parallel requests with each having it's own stream path. <s>So the `finalize` would be triggered for each stream.</s> Instead you could use `forkJoin` to trigger multiple requests in parallel that will *only* emit after all the individual streams complete.

If you're using `toPromise()` to convert the HTTP observable to a promise, avoid doing it. It isn't required here. You could also skip the `from` when using `forkJoin`.

Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

let loading = true;
getUserHTTP(userId).pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    const reqs$ = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {        // let's say oldest 100 posts
      ids.push(
        this.httpClient.post(              // <-- do the HTTP request here
          url,
          getPostQuery(user.username, i)
        )
      );
    }
    return forkJoin(req$);                 // <-- return `forkJoin` here
  }),
  finalize(() => loading = false)
).subscribe({
  next: result => { /* doing stuff */ displayPost(result) },
  error: err => { /* handle errors */ },
  complete: () => { }
});
```

Comment: *So the finalize would be triggered for each stream*. I think that `finalize` gets executed only once, when the source streams completes. What you suggest would happen in case you code `this.httpClient.post(url, query).pipe(finalize())`.

Comment: @Picci: You're right. I've updated the answer. It begs the question why does OP's stream trigger the `finalize` multiple times.

Comment: @MichaelD forkJoin waits for everything to finish which I don't want that behavior as there are slower request in that array of requests. The initial question was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703103/parallel-rxjs-observables-without-waiting-for-all-to-complete/66704120#66704120 . I also assume something (side effect, bad coding) is calling the getUserHTTP() twice that's triggering the finalize as Християн Христов above puts it